# Problem installing coc.vim in vi with vim-plug

Tags: node.js, npm, autocomplete

I just wanted to use vi as an alternative to VSCode and wanted to install the coc.nvim plugin.

So I installed vim-plug via:

```
curl -fLo ~/.vim/autoload/plug.vim --create-dirs \
    https://raw.githubusercontent.com/junegunn/vim-plug/master/plug.vim
```

added these lines to the `~/.vim/vimrc`:

```
call plug#begin('~/.vim/plugged')
Plug 'neoclide/coc.nvim', {'branch': 'release'}
call plug#end()
```

started vi and typed:

```
:PlugInstall
```

But the next time I start vi, I get:

`[coc.nvim] build/index.js not found, please compile coc.nvim by: npm run build`

I then installed node in /usr/local/node and set my $PATH.

```
node -v
v14.17.4
```

and even went into `~.vim/plugged/coc.nvim` and executed `npm run build`. But I'm still getting this error.

System: Ubuntu Linux 20.04

EDIT:
I installed [this](https://tech-doc.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_downloads/e1944fdf57e3ca28d80c863a476bb79e/sample_init.vim) init.vim file and it worked. I would appreciate it, if someone could explain why it works now...

Comment: Use the plugin's dedicated support channels.

Comment: Robert, please do not add the answer to your question. Instead, create an answer below. This way, others will know your question has an answer and can also vote on it. You can even accept the answer if you think it's the best answer to your question. (And if you have follow-up questions, you can create a new question)

Answer (score 0):

You should install yarn utils:

```
curl --compressed -o- -L https://yarnpkg.com/install.sh | bash
```

see here:

`https://github.com/neoclide/coc.nvim/wiki/Install-coc.nvim`

After you install `yarn` utils, you just relaunch nvin and then he try to reinstall all coc parts.